# Matters rarely matter to me - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I think this should be quite a straight forward riddle:

> Invisible to the naked eye.
>   Very little are as small as I.
>   Matters rarely matter to me.
>   I go through them unaffectedly.
>   For me there's no charge, but I do have an anti.
>   and flavours known to amount to three.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're a

> Neutrino

Invisible to the naked eye.
Very little are as small as I.

> Of unknown size, but certainly small. Smaller than an atom. Smaller than an electron, if size means anything at that scale

Matters rarely matter to me.
I go through them unaffectedly.

> Known for interacting with next to nothing (and thus passing straight through most objects). Speculated for some time to have no mass due to their lack of gravitational interactions (now known to have nearly infinitesimally low mass).

For me there's no charge, but I do have an anti.
and flavours known to amount to three.

> Chargeless particle, anti-neutrinos exist with opposite spin, and there are three flavours (referred to as such) - electron, muon and tau neutrinos

Comment: Damn was about to post the same. Have my upvote.

Comment: I was reviewing another answer, and knew it was exactly this. Kudos :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Neutron

Invisible to the naked eye.
Very little are as small as I.

> Neutron are very small

Matters rarely matter to me.
I go through them unaffectedly.

> Neutrons are small enough that they can go through other atoms

For me there's no charge, but I do have an anti.

> Neutrons have no charge. There does exist an anti-neutron

and flavours known to amount to three.

> Not sure about this one.

Answer (score 1):

What is

> a neutron - an invisible particle with *no charge*, an opposite in the form of an anti-neutron, three quarks (flavours), and the ability to penetrate matter due to its small size.

Comment: Please note that Neutrons do not have flavors, Quarks do have flavors though.